# Best way to determine if I have enough time series data and it is spread out evenly?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

I am working with some time series data produced by a sensor at a rate of 1 sample per second, and before I calculate an average for 1 hour, I want to make sure that I have at least 60% of data, but I also want to ensure that the data is sufficiently spread out so that it is not the case that my 60% of data only occurred at the beginning of the hour. Is there some statistical way or algorithm in determining that you have 60% of data and that it is spread out enough to give a confident 1 hour average? What would be my inputs for such an algorithm if one exists?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by having 60% of data? Can you clarify please? And perhaps give a little more information about how your time series data is structured so folks can understand your problem a little easier.

Comment: My apologies, need to come up with a better way of explaining this in a clear and concise way

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.